# Кто хорошо знает javascript, помогите!

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как сделать так чтобы при выборе оценки 5 в первой и в второй четверти появлялось одна кнопка, а при других выборах другая
[image: Фото]

```js
$('.adm-choice label').click(function () {
  $(this).parent().children('label').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');  
  // if ($(this).parent().find('.forward').length == 0) {
  //   $(this).parent().append('<a class="adm-choice_btn forward general" onclick="nextSlide(3,1)">Далее</a>');
  // }
});
```

```css
 .quarter .quarter_text {
  color: #969696;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
 }
 .quarter .quarter_rating label {
  width: 58px;
  border: 2px solid #ca141b;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .quarter .quarter_rating label.selected {
  background-color: #ca141b;
  color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="adm-choice">
  <div class="quarter">
    <div class="quarter_text">first quarter</div>
    <div class="quarter_rating">
      <label>5</label>
      <label>4</label>
      <label>3</label>
      <label>2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="quarter">
    <div class="quarter_text">second quarter</div>
    <div class="quarter_rating">
      <label>5</label>
      <label>4</label>
      <label>3</label>
      <label>2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
<a class="adm-choice_btn forward fmtp">Далее</a>
<a class="adm-choice_btn forward general">Далее</a>
<a class="adm-choice_btn back">Назад</a>
</div>
```

Comment: **КОД**, где ваш текущий код? прочитайте правила сайта пожалуйста.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: сначала нужно описать словами алгоритм, по которому должны появляться кнопки, дальше будет понятнее

Comment: Выложил более подробно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.quarter_rating .vote').on('change', function() {
  const v1 = $('[name=asdf]:checked', '#form1').val();
  const v2 = $('[name=asdf]:checked', '#form2').val();
  if (v1 && v2) {
    $('.forward').removeClass('link-hide');
    if (v1 == 5 && v2 == 5) {
      $('.forward').removeClass('fmtp').addClass('general').attr('href', 'google.com')
    } else {
      $('.forward').removeClass('general').addClass('fmtp').attr('href', 'ya.ru')
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.quarter .quarter_text {
  color: #969696;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.quarter .quarter_rating label {
  width: 58px;
  border: 2px solid #ca141b;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.quarter .quarter_rating label.selected {
  background-color: #ca141b;
  color: #fff;
}

.link-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="adm-choice">
  <div class="quarter">
    <div class="quarter_text">first quarter</div>
    <form class="quarter_rating" id="form1">
      <label for="radio-btn1">
        <input type="radio" class="vote" id="radio-btn1" name="asdf" value="5">
        <span>5</span>
      </label>
      <label for="radio-btn2">
        <input type="radio" class="vote" id="radio-btn2" name="asdf" value="4">
        <span>4</span>
      </label>
      <label for="radio-btn3">
        <input type="radio" class="vote" id="radio-btn3" name="asdf" value="3">
        <span>3</span>
      </label>
      <label for="radio-btn4">
        <input type="radio" class="vote" id="radio-btn4" name="asdf" value="2">
        <span>2</span>
      </label>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="quarter">
    <div class="quarter_text">second quarter</div>
    <form class="quarter_rating" id="form2">
      <label for="radio-btn11">
        <input type="radio" class="vote" id="radio-btn11" name="asdf" value="5">
        <span>5</span>
      </label>
      <label for="radio-btn12">
        <input type="radio" class="vote" id="radio-btn12" name="asdf" value="4">
        <span>4</span>
      </label>
      <label for="radio-btn13">
        <input type="radio" class="vote" id="radio-btn13" name="asdf" value="3">
        <span>3</span>
      </label>
      <label for="radio-btn14">
        <input type="radio" class="vote" id="radio-btn14" name="asdf" value="2">
        <span>2</span>
      </label>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <a class="adm-choice_btn back">Назад</a>
    <a class="adm-choice_btn forward link-hide" href="ya.ru">Далее</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Мадияр Альжанов зачем 2 кнопки "далее" я не понял, поэтому одну из них убрал

Comment: Если оценки за 1 и 2 четверть 5 то кнопка далее на одну страницу, но если другие оценки то уже на другую страницу

Comment: Кнопка назад как стояло так и стоит)

Comment: @МадиярАльжанов если две 5, <a class="general"> появляется или <a class="fmtp"> ?

Comment: Ты наверное не правильно понял, те у кого 5 и 5 переходят на страницу для отличников, а те у кого 5 и 4 и.т.д то они переходят на страницу для сдачи другого экзамена

Comment: @МадиярАльжанов, там не класс должен меняться, a href у ссылки

Comment: Это я просто чтобы было понятно

Comment: @МадиярАльжанов обновил, отличники на гугл.ком переходят, ударники на я.ру, чтоб было понятно где редактировать тебе ссылки

Comment: Спасибо большое! Но если не трудно мог бы сделать так чтобы кнопка далее выходила после выбора оценок?

Comment: @МадиярАльжанов что значит выходила?

Comment: Тут кнопка Далее уже стоит, оно не должно в начале высвечиваться, должно появиться после как нажмут на оценки

Comment: @МадиярАльжанов обновил

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!